# Calculate the dimension of the latent space

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am implementing an autoencoder and I want to calculate the dimension of the latent space.

Let's say that I want a 3D latent space. So from my code how to calculate the current latent space.
Thank you

my current code:

```
x = Input(shape=(28, 28,1)) 

# Encoder
conv1_1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1_1)
conv1_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1_2)
conv1_3 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
h = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1_3)

# Decoder
conv2_1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(h)
up1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_1)
conv2_2 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
up2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_2)
conv2_3 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(up2)
up3 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(conv2_3)
r = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(up3)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=x, outputs=r)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of an Autoencoder is shaped in the form of a funnel, with the number of nodes decreasing as we move from the input layer to a layer (shown in red) known as "latent space." From latent space, the number of nodes appears to increase again until it reaches the output layer, where it equals the number of nodes in the input layer.

[image]

From the [model summary](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/c42ec4436ed84521ce56d2fd0371c6e2/74746366.ipynb#scrollTo=mHhvI7G89sxR) we can see that the 7th layer is the latent space which is the compressed form of the input data.

```
tf.keras.backend.ndim(autoencoder.layers[6].output)
```

To get the dimension of a particular layer from a model you can use the above API. Thank you!